# How to add two variable values in dropdown field in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a dropdown field, in that I need to show two query values.

```
a = table_first.first.name
b = table_second.all.collect{ |tc| [ "#{tc.name} [#{tc.number}]", tc.id ] }
```

Using `options_for_select`, I want to display these two values `a` and `b` in the dropdown field.
Is it possible ?

Comment: please specify with an example so contributor gets a better idea of what you want exactly. because variable a in just one value and b is an array of your options. also, you can merge both values(a and b) and set in option tag and fulfill your need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can insert the first value into the second array.

```rb
options_for_select(b.unshift(a))
```

which should return in something like

```html
<option value="first">first</option>
<option value="1">Second [1]</option>
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

## Edit

Full example in Rails console with values

```rb
[13] pry(main)> table_first = "first"
=> "first"

[14] pry(main)> table_second = [["Second [2]", 2]]
=> [["Second [2]", 2]]

[15] pry(main)> ApplicationController.helpers.options_for_select(table_second.unshift(table_first))

=> "<option value=\"first\">first</option>\n<option value=\"2\">Second [2]</option>"
```

Comment: No, It's not working for me. Showing only the b query values and not a.

Comment: Then please include a full example with the example values from `table_first` and `table_second`. See my edit, I tried this and it worked for me.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this fixed your problem.

Answer (score -1):

yes it's possible.

```
options_for_select(table_second.all.map { |obj| "#{obj.name}__#{obj.id}", obj.id })
```

Comment: This is only showing the second values, so obviously wrong!

Comment: @BehrouzMoslem: This _is_ an answer. It just appears to be a _wrong_ answer. But [wrong answers are still answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).